# HTML does not display as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 files,
test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="./test/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>test1</p>
<p>test2</p>
<p>test3</p>
<p>test4</p>
<p id="11" ></p>
<script> $( "#11" ).load( "end.html") </script>

</body>
</html>
```

end.html

```html
info:No
Creation time:2020.05.01-17.03
Change the time: <script>document.write(document.lastModified);</script>
```

There are two display effects:

[Number One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0eCu.png) and [Number Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiCnX.png)

Reproducing this effect:

> test1
>
> test2
>
> test3
>
> test4
>
> info:No
>
> Creation time:2020.05.01-17.03
>
> Change the time:05/24/2020 09:19:23

Comment: You want to merge two HTML files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="./test/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>test1</p>
<p>test2</p>
<p>test3</p>
<p>test4</p>
<script src="end.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

end.js

```
document.writeln("<p>info:No");
document.writeln("Creation time:2020.05.01-17.03</p>");
document.writeln("Change the time:<script>document.write(document.lastModified);</script>");
```

ok

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your JQuery URL is being picked up, maybe add a direct link in header of your test.html

```
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also, don't forget to close your statements off with a semi-colon

```
<p>test4</p>
<p id="11" ></p> <script>$("#11").load("end.html");</script>
```

Also, I don't know if that script is running there, maybe do the following at the bottom of your page instead of putting the script tag there. This will execute the line when the HTML Dom is loaded

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#11').load("end.html");

});
</script>
```